# How can I use my iMac as a network for my iPad 2?

Tags: ipad, network, imac

My iMac goes online via a Verizon wireless device.  I don't know what my "network" is called and how to use it to go online on my iPad 2.

Comment: Title clarification: do you want your iMac and iPad to use the same network, or are you creating a new network on your iMac for your iPad to use?

Comment: @bneely If I understood it correctly, he has a 3G USB adapter for his iMac. He wants his iPad to go online and would like to share the internet from the iMac to the iPad.

Answer (score 3):

Your iMac can use it's network card to share it's internet access via **[Internet sharing](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8156.html)**.

The setup is very fast and simple. **Password encryption** is supported.

You can define the settings in **System Preferences > Sharing**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of the network your iMac is joining, open System Preferences (which you can do from the Apple menu at the top left of your screen, in the menu bar).

[image]

Then choose Network from the System Preferences window (which is near the center of the window on my Lion system). Select "Wi-Fi" on the left of the Network pref pane, and on the right you should see "Network name:" and the name of the wireless network should appear to the right of it.

[image]

On the iPad, you will need to launch the Settings application. Select General on the left side of the screen, then choose Network on the right side of the screen. Tap Wi-Fi, and select the network name that matches the network name used on your iMac.